# Cannot find Twitter kit in fabric - in iOS

Tags: twitter, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

I can see Crashlytics, Answers, Stripe etc. but cannot find Twitter in Fabric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

EDIT April 2019: As Sunil mentioned below, Twitter Kit is no longer available and has been deprecated by Twitter: [https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/overview)

Comment: Note: `Twitter will be discontinuing support for Twitter Kit on October 31, 2018`. Read the blog post here: https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html