# how to integrate twitter in android for twitter login after it's removal from fabric?

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter, twitter-fabric, twitter-login

I am trying to integrate twitter login.
The login button of twitter is grayed out.
I have read somewhere that i have to add these line before setting content view to make it work:

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig(
                getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key),
                getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));

        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));//here,i am having problem

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cover);
```

But android studio does not recognize 'Fabric' .It has red color.This is the  code:

> Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

Also, there is a red underline below 'Twitter',and i have the following error:

> 'Twitter(com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterConfig)' has private
> access in 'com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Twitter'

Also,i have tried fabric plugin of android studio,but there is no option for twitter login:

[image: fabric plugin]

Comment: You need to add fabric plugin to your android studio.

use this link: https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/material-design/twitter-login-android-tutorial-using-fabric-twitter-login-kit/

Comment: i have the plugin,but there is no option for twitter login.these are the following options:crashlytics,answers,optimizely,stripe,amazon cognito sync,appsee,mapbox,pubnub,game analytics,zendesk,and branch.

Comment: have you gone through the link i provided.

Comment: yes,but there is no twitter in this:  https://i0.wp.com/www.androidtutorialpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/twitter11.png?ssl=1

Comment: i have added the snapshot of my fabric plugin.As you can see, there is no option for twitter.

Comment: Maybe you need to update the latest plugin.

Comment: i think this is the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44798662/7790948

Comment: So you can use "twitter4j" instead of fabric.Use this link : http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-android-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find Twitter kit in fabric - in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580899/cannot-find-twitter-kit-in-fabric-in-ios)

Comment: my problem is solved

Comment: this solved my problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44840626/7790948

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

write this:

```
        TwitterConfig.Builder builder=new TwitterConfig.Builder(this);
        builder.twitterAuthConfig(authConfig);
        Twitter.initialize(builder.build());
```

Also,you need to add this line in gradle(app level) :

> compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'

Answer (score 3):

Add dependencies and repositories in build.gradle

```
dependencies {


 compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.0'
  compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.0'
  compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.0'
  compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.1.0'
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}
```

Initialize Twitter Kit in oncreate() of Activity

```
Twitter.initialize(this);
```

Add your API key and secret to your application resources.

```
<resources>
  <string android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
  <string android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

Add Twitter Button in xml

```
<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Initialize Twitter Button and get TwitterSession.. in success of that get User info

```
loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
        // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
        Log.e("result", "result " + result);
        TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
        AccountService accountService = twitterApiClient.getAccountService();
        Call<User> call = accountService.verifyCredentials(true, true, true);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User> result) {
                //here we go User details
                Log.e("result", "result user " + result);
                String imageUrl = result.data.profileImageUrl;
                String email = result.data.email;
                String userName = result.data.name;
                System.out.println(imageUrl);
                System.out.println(email);
                System.out.println(userName);




        }
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
    // Do something on failure
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
});
```

If your button is in fragment, Add following code in activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //verificationFragment is my fragment
    verificationFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Add following code in fragment

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}
```

Comment: i am not getting any value in email & photourl

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. Due to Google's acquisition of Fabric from Twitter, Twitter Kit is no longer available via Fabric. You should follow the instructions on their [developer site](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/overview). The changes you would need to change are as follows.

1) Remove Twitter from your Fabric init call.

2) Add the following to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  // Include all the Twitter APIs
  compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
  // (Optional) Monetize using mopub
  compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.0.0'
}
```

3) Make sure jcenter is in your repositories scope:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}
```

4) Initialize Twitter in your Application's onCreate():

```
public class CustomApplication {
  public void onCreate() {
    Twitter.initialize(this);
  }
}
```

5) Add your API key and secret to your resources:

```
 <resources>
  <string android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
  <string android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: I didn't quite follow your question @komalakhani - but it's added in step five.

Comment: Don't worry..I got the answer..btw Thanks:)

Comment: @Mike will you please let me know how to set callback URL for twitter login in my android app, I am creating a deep link but it is not working..